# Regex for: 6 digits or 0-6 signs (digits or stars) with at least one star

Tags: regex

How to write regex to validate this pattern?

```
123456 - correct
*1 - correct
1* - correct
124** - correct
*1*2 - correct
* - correct
123456* - incorrect (size 7)
12345 - incorrect (size 5 without stars)
```

tried:

```
^[0-9]{6}$|^(([0-9]){1,6}([*]){1,5}){1,6}+$
```

But it allows to have more than 6 numbers and don't allow for star to be before number.
There is no minimum/maximum count of "*" sign (but max count for all signs is 6).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here you go:

```
^(?:\d{6}|(?=.*\*)[\d*]{1,6}|)$
```

Here is what it does:

```
^            <-- Start of the string (we don't want to capture more than that)
  (?:          <-- Start a non captured group (it will be used to do the "or" part)
    \d{6}          <-- 6 digits, nothing more
    |            <-- OR
    (?=.*\*)       <-- Look ahead for a '*' (you could replace the first * with {0,5})
    [\d*]          <-- digits or '*'
    {1,6}          <-- repeated one to six times (we know from the look ahead that there will be at least one '*'
    |            <-- OR (nothing)
  )            <-- End the non capturing group
$            <-- End of the string
```

---

I'm not quite sure if you want the empty case (but you said 0 to 6), if you actually want 1 to 6 just remove the last `|`

Answer (score 1):

/ ([0-9] {6} )    |   ( ( [0-9]{0-5} & [*]{1-5} ) {0-6})/

something like this?

Comment: 6 digits from 0 to 9 OR 0 to 5 digits from 0 to 9 with at least 1 * in it with a length of maximum 6

Comment: I dont know why but it not working correctly for me, using [gskinner.com](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) to check

Comment: because I forgot to exit the * with a \ in front of it, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that you will have to try for each position that the * might have, like this:

```
/([0-9]{6}|\*[0-9][0-9\*]{0,4}|[0-9]\*[0-9\*]{0,4}|[0-9]{2}\*[0-9\*]{0,3}|[0-9]{3}\*[0-9\*]{0,2}|[0-9]{4}\*[0-9\*]?|[0-9]{5}\*)/
```

**Edit:**

The above solution will however not allow **2

And I was wrong. You can do it with a look forward like Colin did. That is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
[1-6]{6}|([1-6]|\*){1,6}[^123456]
```

this works for the inputs you gave...

If you want something else then update me...

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with just a regex. You also need a length check. However, here is a regex that will help.

```
([\d*]*\*[\d*]*)|(\d{6})
```

To validate the input, try something like this:

```
validate(input)
{
    regex = "([\d*]*\*[\d*]*)|(\d{6})";
    digitregex = ".*\d.*"; // this makes sure they aren't all stars

    return (input.length < 7 and regex.matches(input) and digitregex.matches(input))
}
```

Comment: Wha...? Is the lookahead a standard regex feature?

Comment: Hmm, the way I understand it, lookahead is not possible in formal regular expressions, but it is in language implementations. Thanks for teaching me something. :)

Comment: Just for fun you can do it without lookahead, with a lot of `|` and `\*[\d*]{0,5}|\d\*[\d*]{0,4}|\d{2}\*[\d*]{0,3}| ....` But as I said you would only want to do that because it's funny.

Answer (score 0):

if any digits 0..9 are allowed try this regexp `[0-9*]{2,6}`
if only digits 1..6 as in your example `[1-6*]{2,6}`

it's a bit tricky cause also `12345` will be validated as correct

[example here](http://rubular.com/r/0FSEjs1Qf1)

You'll actually need a solution with [look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) as already suggested by [@Colin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10107608/397667)

Comment: will it match `*1` and `1*` and `*1*2`?

Comment: in your regex it has to be 6 digits, but in his question it is 6 digits maximum, no?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**  (updated)

```
([0-6]{6})|([0-6\*]{1,6})
```

It should work...

Comment: it allows less than 6 numbers (only) to be passed so its not working

Comment: The `([0-6\*]{1,6})` bit says that you can have less than 6 digits as you don't have to have '*'.